# Arduino Pro Mini (3.3V) ATMEGA328P: Measure 0-5V/0-10V and 0-20mA analog inputs

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, components, circuit-protection

I'm looking on how to design circuitry in order to safely measure 0-5V and 0-10V analog inputs from my bare bones "pro mini alike arduino" (ATMEGA328P) powered from 3.3V external power source.

This is my base schematic:

[image]

I was thinking to use a simple voltage divider for the voltage measurement, but I'm not sure. I mean, the board will be used in a industrial environment and a voltage divider seems to be a bad choice.

Also for the current loop (0-20mA and 4-20mA), inspired from this *DFRobots breakout ([SEN0262](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DFRobot/Wiki/master/SEN0262/res/%5BSEN0262%5D(V1.0)%20Schematic.pdf))*, this current measurement solution looks quite good and safe:

[image]

It is a good way to go this current measurement method?

About the voltage measurement, does anyone is able to give me some advice on measuring those voltages in a "safe way" (e.g., protecting the microcontroller from high voltages and low voltages wiring errors)?

Answer (score 1):

For industrial environments the way to go is fully isolated, since you don't know where your signal's ground come from. Also EMC requirements are quite stricter.

For example, your 4-20 input schematic is limited in common mode from the power supply ground. That will give issue when there is a severe ground surge or something. Also I don't see any kind of filtering or EMI suppression measure.

There are application notes from major IC manufactures on 'reference designs' with all the protections needed for a given application (included the industrial ones).